# Single vs multiple functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, methods

I'm developing a model for a MVC project I'm working on.  I was wondering though if it's better to have multiple functions for a task or a single function for each way it can be handled.  For example, is it better to have something like:

```
public function get($identifiers = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    if ($identifiers != null) {
        if (is_array($identifiers)) {
            $this->db->where($identifiers);
        } else {
            $this->db->where($this->_key, $identifiers);
            $method = 'row'.($this->_return_array ? '_array' : '');
            return $this->db->get($this->_table)->$method();
        }
    }

    if ($limit != null) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset || null);
    }

    if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->_order);
    }

    $method = 'result'.($this->_return_array ? '_array' : '');
    return $this->db->get($this->_table)->$method();
}
```

That handles multiple cases or to have separate functions such as

```
get($id) {}
get_where($where) {}
get_all() {}
```

and so on.

Comment: I think the second version is better if you want something like "clean code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate functions adhere to the Single Responsibility principle much closer than one function that tries to do many things. This means that you'll have smaller functions that are easier to understand, debug, modify, and test. In almost every case you're better off with multiple specific functions versus one monolithic one.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling after writing the first function that it was not the right way of going about things. I guess that's what happens when I try to get fancy with my code :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what's going on inside those functions. 
If most of business logic is the same and just input parameters differ (let's say, you need to prepare different arguments, but after that the logic is the same), then I would go with single function. 
In other cases I'd do mutliple smaller functions - it's more maintainable and easier to understand what's going on there.